# Synced CSV File Google Drive - Not Filling out Georeference field for visual

Tags: carto, google-drive

I Have a JS account on Cartodb with the sync option for data.

I have created code to upload CSV file to Google Drive of all login activity of our Google Accounts for the last day. If I select this document as a data source without adding sync option, it converts the ip_address column I have to the co-ords using Georeference via IP Addressing.

If I select the sync option instead for the table data, the data syncs correctly but I can't see where to setup the georeference column for the map view. The Georeference section in the top right drop down is greyed out.

Please tell me I haven't upgraded our account without this feature working...

Answer (score 1):

We already solved this question in support. :-)

We will be releasing automatic IP addresses georeferenciation in the next weeks. Meanwhile, if you create a Sync table, you won't be able to georeference tables manually as data will be erased the next time the file synchronizes. That's why data edition is locked in Sync tables, to avoid the deletion of your customized data.