# Georeference disabled in CartoDB synced dataset?

Tags: carto, geocoding, table

If I upload a dataset with synced option enable then I haven't the option to do the geocoding.

[image]

Is that normal?

How I can geocode the addresses?

If manually I can't do the geocoding, how I can do programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synced CSV File Google Drive - Not Filling out Georeference field for visual](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123254/synced-csv-file-google-drive-not-filling-out-georeference-field-for-visual)

Answer (score 2):

Geocoding is generally unavailable for synced datasets in CartoDB, because each sync would cost geocoding credits which would end up charging the users an exorbitant amount. However, if you have columns called "latitude" AND "longitude", "city" or "IP addresses" your georeferencing will be done automatically upon each sync. Maybe that could be a workaround for you or you could try using a google script with SQL to geocode a google spreadsheet and then sync that to CartoDB.